# React Devtools not showing <View> component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-debugger, flipper

React Devtools not showing `<View>` component in React Native.

I tested it with Flipper and RNDebugger tools and I still cannot see my `<View>` components in tree.

I am using newest React, Recat Native and devtools. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found answer...

There are filters in React Devtools what needs to be removed to be able to see View component:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flipper in mac system than It's working properly but in window system this problem is occurred due to port number issue. I have solved this problem using below command in window system.You can try using this command.

[image]

react-native run-android --port 8097.